# Getting a lognormal from some percentiles

Tags: r, logging, stata, distribution, normal-distribution

I am trying to do something in Stata or R.

I have percentiles of a wage distribution (percentiles 10, 25, 50, 75, 90) and I want to estimate a lognormal distribution to fit them. In Stata there is a command `lognfit` that fits a lognormal to unit record data, but not to percentile points.

Is it worth using Stata's `gmm` command, using my five datapoints to estimate the two parameters of the lognormal as an overidentified system?

Comment: Answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6022/estimating-a-distribution-based-on-three-percentiles).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Stata solution.

I leave to others the attractions of `gmm`. You could also regress the logged quantiles on the corresponding quantiles of a standard normal distribution. Here is code embedded in an experiment to see how well the method works. We generate 1000 samples each of size 1000 from a lognormal which is a normal with mean 1 and SD 2 exponentiated. Here it is `rangestat` that does all the regressions, one for each sample.

```
clear 
set obs 1000000
set seed 1066 
set scheme s1color 

gen y = exp(rnormal(1, 2)) 
egen sample = seq(), block(1000) 
collapse (p10) y10=y (p25) y25=y (p50) y50=y (p75) y75=y (p90) y90=y, by(sample)  

reshape long y, i(sample) j(p) 
gen pred = invnormal(p/100)
gen log_y = log(y)

* must install from SSC using: ssc install rangestat
rangestat (reg) log_y pred, interval(sample 0 0) 

qnorm b_cons if p==10, name(G1) yli(1) ytitle("") subtitle(mean known to be 1) yla(, ang(h)) 
qnorm b_pred if p==10, name(G2) yli(2) ytitle("") subtitle(SD known to be 2) yla(, ang(h)) 

graph combine G1 G2
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for your responses.

I was trying with both programs. In R for example I was using the package `library(rriskDistributions)`, specifically something like

```
    ## example with only two quantiles

    q <- stats::qlnorm(p = c(0.025, 0.975), meanlog = 4, sdlog = 0.8)

    old.par <- graphics::par(mfrow = c(2, 3))
    get.lnorm.par(p = c(0.025, 0.975), q = q)
    get.lnorm.par(p = c(0.025, 0.975), q = q, fit.weights = c(100, 1), 
    scaleX = c(0.1, 0.001))
    get.lnorm.par(p = c(0.025, 0.975), q = q, fit.weights = c(1, 100), 
    scaleX = c(0.1, 0.001))
    get.lnorm.par(p = c(0.025, 0.975), q = q, fit.weights = c(10, 1))
    get.lnorm.par(p = c(0.025, 0.975), q = q, fit.weights = c(1, 10))
    graphics::par(old.par)
```

In Stata I'm trying with GMM based on https://blog.stata.com/2015/12/03/understanding-the-generalized-method-of-moments-gmm-a-simple-example/

```
    matrix I = I(1)

    mat lis I

    gmm ((y - exp({xb: percentile_10 percentile_20 percentile_25 
    percentile_30 percentile_50 percentile_60 percentile_75 
    percentile_90})) / exp({xb:})), instruments(percentile_10 
    percentile_20 percentile_25 percentile_30 percentile_50 percentile_60 
    percentile_75 percentile_90) twostep
```

Here is a first attempt to use GMM, of course I'm missing something.

The answer from Nick Cox was great. I'll try to fit my data with this approach.

Comment: Answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6022/estimating-a-distribution-based-on-three-percentiles).